# custom ActionBar not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My code for showing custom ActionBar is given below. I am using the slidingmenu library from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     View customActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_actionbar,
                new LinearLayout(this), false);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBar);



    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    slidingMenu=getSlidingMenu();
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(100);

    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            slidingMenu.showMenu();
        }
    });


}
```

**Markup for the custom ActionBar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
              android:dividerPadding="12dp"
              android:showDividers="middle">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
                  style="@style/CustomActionButton">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_cancel_holo_light" style="@style/ActionButtonImage" />
        <TextView android:text="DISCARD" style="@style/ActionButtonText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/action_done" style="@style/CustomActionButton">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_done_holo_light" style="@style/ActionButtonImage" />
        <TextView android:text="DONE" style="@style/ActionButtonText" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this application, the default dark ActionBar is showing not the custom one. How to fix this ?

Comment: how about this .. View customActionBar = getSupportActionBar(); or View customActionBar = getActionBar(); view.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_actionbar);

Comment: My min sdk is 11. So no problem with getActionBar()

Comment: Did you set directly  view.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_actionbar);  ?. And still not loading ?

Comment: Your using SherlockAction bar library ?

Comment: no I am not using that

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it his way:

```
/*Inflate your custom actionBar layout*/
final ViewGroup customActionBar = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_actionbar, null);

/*Get actionbar*/
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

/*set custom view*/
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

/*Define custom view*/
actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBar );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sherlock Sliding menu, then you have to use Sherlock actionbar.

If you dont want sherlock then check this,  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

Try this before setting custom content of action bar

```
ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```